# How can I change the point color in my scatter plot for each column of my dataframe (one color for each column)?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to change the color of my data in a Scatter Plot.
I have 5 columns (only 3 with values for my Plot) with 264.000 rows, this my dataframe:

```
ID1         ID2         dN      dS      t
QJY77946    NP_073551   0.0241  0.1402  0.1479
QJY77954    NP_073551   0.0119  0.0912  0.0870
QJY77954    QJY77946    0.0119  0.0439  0.0566
```

My Scatter Plot when I make Column dN vs dS is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVoxR.png)

My question: How I can change the color for points in each column (one color for column dN, other for the column dS...)??

I´m using ggplot2 and tidyverse libraries in RStudio, this is my code for Scatter Plot:

Any idea or help is welcome!
Thank!

````
  ggplot(aes(x = dN, y = t)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "Pairwise Comparison S Protein",
       subtitle = "dS vs dN with YN00",
       x = "dS rate",
       y = "dN rate") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text())```
````

Comment: Your graph  is plotting `dN` against `t` but your axis are labelled `dN` versus `dS`,  Do you want one graph with `dN` and `dS` plotted against `t`? In which case transforming the data into long format would be the way to go `tidyr::pivot_longer` is your friend in this case.

Comment: If you are plotting  `dN` and `dS` you would need to explain how you want to use colour as each point on the scatter plot comprises pairwise `dN` and `dS` values.

Comment: My plan is to make one scatter plot for dN vs dS, dN vs t and dS vs t. The principal idea is, for example, red for all values in the column dN, blue for the column dS and green for t column.